# Can anyone give me some hints about this question(Family tree)?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

It comes from my homework assignments. There is a family tree

```
                             a  +  b
                         /   |    |   \ 
                        c+u  d+c  e+w  f
                     / | \        / \
                 m+x  n+y  o      p  q
                  |
                  r
```

a and b is the oldest. and every married people the second person is not part of the original family.
Now I need to write the spouse, sibling, children ,grandchildren, parents and grandparents function.

I wrote the list as below:
 **( (father mother) chlid1 child2 child3)**

```
(((a b) c d e f) ((c u) m n o) ((d v) nil) ((e w) p q) (f nil) ((m x) r) ((n y) nil) (o nil) (p nil) (q nil)  )
```

I have some problems with sibling function, here is my code.

```
(defun sibling  (arglst lst)  
 (cond
        ((eql 
             arglst (cdr (car lst))) 
                 (rest (cdr lst))
         )
   (T (sibling (rest lst) arglst))

)
```

I knew it was wrong, but I don't how to revise it..  and I also need some help with other functions. hope can get some hints from u guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework, I won't give the full solution, but this should suffice for you to solve the rest:

```
(defparameter *family* '(((a b) c d e f)
                         ((c u) m n o)
                         ((d v) nil)
                         ((e w) p q)
                         (f nil)
                         ((m x) r)
                         ((n y) nil)
                         (o nil)
                         (p nil)
                         (q nil)))

(defun siblings (person family)
  "Return a list of PERSON's siblings."
  (remove person (cdr (find person family :key #'cdr :test #'member))))

(defun siblingsp (person1 person2 family)
  "Are PERSON1 and PERSON2 siblings?"
  (find person2 (siblings person1 family)))

(defun parents (person family)
  "Return a list of PERSON's parents."
  (car (find person family :key #'cdr :test #'member)))

(defun parentp (parent child family)
  "Is PARENT a parent of CHILD?"
  (find parent (parents child family)))
```

Try it:

```
CL-USER> (siblings 'p *family*)
(Q)
CL-USER> (siblingsp 'q 'p *family*)
P
CL-USER> (parents 'p *family*)
(E W)
```

Now, to find the grandparents for example, you just have to understand what grandparents are: (A list of) The parents of both parents. Then, ask yourself how it is for grandchildren. Finally, the `spouse` function should be rather easy, given this example.

Comment: BTW: Also take this as an example as to how to format your Lisp code, esp. how to indent, place your parens, and how to name variables and parameters.

Comment: Is there something left unclear, or something you didn't understand?

Comment: yes It' very helpful, I just finished today. there is one thing I cannot work out. about spouse function. see answer blew plz..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it can only return first level and second level,for example. a returns b, c returns u . but when  I entere **m** ,it returns an erro :

`- MEMBER: A proper list must not end with F`.

I checked the code and didn't find any problems. why it cannot search the third level?  but it can find grandchildren,so I think if it can do grandchildren search why it cannot do spouse search? is there something wrong with `Member` function?  anyway, your code is really simple and easy to read and understand. Thanks a lot.

```
(defun spouse ( family-tree2 person) ;Find person's spouse
   (remove person (car (find person family-tree2 :key #'car :test #'member)))
);end
```

Comment: The problem is, that before `spouse` gets to `((m x) r)` it processes `(f nil)`, where `f` is not a list. `member` chokes on that. Try testing, wether the first element of the list is a list, or changing the representation for unwed persons like this: `((f) nil)`. (Another thing: Don't put closing parentheses on their own lines. It will take a little time to get used to, but other Lisp programmers expect your code to look a certain way. One reads the indentation, not the parentheses. Use an editor with proper paren-matching. Also: Why `family-tree2` and not just `family-tree` or `family`?)

Comment: Thanks ,I think I got it .  family-tree2 is an given constant by my teacher.